# Output time and date with fractional time without using C++11

Tags: c++

I am trying to find a solution on outputting current date and time (with milliseconds) in the following format: 2018-01-28 15:51:02.159

This could be solved using using C++17 and `chrono::floor<chrono::seconds>` or C++11  `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>`

Unfortunately I cannot use C++17 or C++11 - are there any other not too advanced options out there? If not, I would appreciate some help in getting the formatting correct without fractional time, like this: 2018-01-28 15:51:02

Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: cppreference is your friend: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [localtime](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) and this post [Getting current time with milliseconds](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11921/getting-current-time-with-milliseconds):

```
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdio>  // handle type conversions 
#include <sys/time.h>

int main (void) {

    timeval curTime;
    gettimeofday(&curTime, NULL);
    int milli = curTime.tv_usec / 1000;

    char buffer [80];
    strftime(buffer, 80, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(&curTime.tv_sec));

    char currentTime[84] = "";
    sprintf(currentTime, "%s.%d", buffer, milli);
    printf("current date time: %s \n", currentTime);

    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
current date time: 2018-01-28 14:45:52.486
```

Comment: just one more question, my gcc returns a `warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘__suseconds_t {aka long int}’ may alter its value [-Wconversion] int milli = curTime.tv_usec / 1000;` Do you possibly know why/how to solve it?

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing that out, try replacing the header `<stdio.h>` with the c-standard [`<cstdio>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/). see edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

As C++ inherits it's time units from C a guaranteed solution is to fall back to the C library (can't remember seeing a pure C++ version... this keeps as much C++ as I can):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>                // std::setw()...
#include <cstdlib>

#include <sys/time.h>             // gettimeofday() and friends


int main(void)
{
     struct timeval  tv;
     struct tm       local_tm;
     char            print_time[30];

     gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);
     localtime_r( &tv.tv_sec, &local_tm );
     strftime( print_time, sizeof print_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.", &local_tm );


     std::cout << print_time  << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << ( tv.tv_usec + 500 ) / 1000 << std::endl;

     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You could of course skip **strftime()** by a series of **setw()** calls, but I think **strftime()** is cleaner.

Comment: Many thanks! Do you possibly know how computation heavy this is?

Comment: Always ware of generic "computation time" estimates as they can be so specific (hit... write some benchmarks and run t hem in your environment.. be sure you are not testing your cache).  getimeofday() and localtime_r() will be fast. gmtime_r() can be faster as it doesn't need to fiddle with time zones, but you get UTC(GMT) time, which I tend to prefer within server aps. Would assume you can do better with avoiding strftime() to print your integers.